# Visual triggered a breakpoint c++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm new at coding and I tried to write a hangman game. The program chooses randomly one of 10 words, displays only '_' and after every guess the screen refreshes.

The problem is that sometimes the loop is displayed 2X the whole screen.So, I tried using -

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

but then Visual says to me that program triggered a breakpoint. What is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void showLogo();
int main()
{
    int number, amount;
    int mistake = 5;
    int wrongLetter = 0;
    char letter;
    char tab[13];
    char unknown[13];
    char usedLetters[5];
    char *wsk;

    srand(time(NULL));
    number = rand() % 10;  //choose one of 10 words

    string words[10] ={"LONGITUDINAL","UNFORTUNATELY","EXPLANATORY",
                       "PERENNIAL","UNPUTDOWNABLE","REMORSELESS",
                       "INTERMITTENT","ADJUDICATE","INERSTITIAL",
                       "MALPOSED" };

    amount = size(words[number]);  
    strcpy_s(tab, words[number].c_str()); //string to char

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        unknown[i] = '_';
    }

    while (mistake)
    {
        int noOfGuessed = 0;
        showLogo();

        cout << "You have: " << mistake << " chances." << endl << endl;
        cout << "Used words: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < wrongLetter; i++)
        {
            cout << usedLetters[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {   
            cout << unknown[i] << "  ";
        }
        cout << "\t Enter a letter: ";

        letter = getchar();
        letter = toupper(letter);

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            if (letter == tab[i] && unknown[i] == '_')
            {
                wsk = &unknown[i];
                *wsk = letter;
                noOfGuessed++;
            }
        }

        if (noOfGuessed == 0)
        {
            mistake--;
            usedLetters[wrongLetter] = letter;
            wrongLetter++;
        }

        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        system("cls");
    }

    system("pause");    
    return 0;
}

void showLogo()
{
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t HANGMAN" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: A) Reduce the code sample B) Specify on *which line* the breakpoint occured.

Comment: You're calling `strcpy_s()` with the wrong number of arguments, how did this compile?

Comment: Why are you using C strings at all, just use `std::string`.

Comment: Use `std::getline(std::cin, my_word_string);` and you should have no problems with the line endings.  The variable should be `std::string my_word_string;`.

Comment: Does it really work to mix stdio function `getcar()` with C++ stream `cin.ignore()`?

Comment: *Don't cross the streams*.  The C language I/O may not use the same streams as C++ I/O (`cin`).  Prefer to use C++ I/O only.

Comment: @Barmar There's a template version of `strcpy_s` for arrays that is used here.

Answer (score 0):

`ignore()` will set the eof bit of cin, and leave the stream in an error state. You should always clear the stream error bits after calling `ignore()`.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cin.clear();
```